# How do i stop my Watson Assistant from auto-correcting the user input

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, autocorrect

Can anyone help me solve this issue
The screenshot attached below is self explanatory
[image]

It is auto-correcting **sufyan** to **Susan**
The value for the context variable is

```
"<? input.text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.text.substring(1) ?>"
```

The motive here is to simply convert lowercase name **sufyan** to **Sufyan**
or for that case any Indian name.

But the auto-correct has now become a hindrance.

I want the assistant to interact with the user in the later part using his/her name.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure autocorrection in [your bot settings](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime#dialog-runtime-spell-check-disable).

Answer (score 1):

Along with Henrik’s answer, it’s good to learn about fuzzy matching in Watson Assistant as it runs before autocorrection

How is spelling autocorrection related to fuzzy matching?

Fuzzy matching helps your assistant recognize dictionary-based entity mentions in user input. It uses a dictionary lookup approach to match a word from the user input to an existing entity value or synonym in the skill's training data. For example, if the user enters boook, and your training data contains a @reading_material entity with a book value, then fuzzy matching recognizes that the two terms (boook and book) mean the same thing.

When you enable both autocorrection and fuzzy matching, the fuzzy matching function runs before autocorrection is triggered. If it finds a term that it can match to an existing dictionary entity value or synonym, it adds the term to the list of words that belong to the skill, and does not correct it.

Check the complete [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime#dialog-runtime-spell-check-vs-fuzzy-matching) before turning of autocorrection

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following context variable:

```
"<? input.original_text.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + input.original_text.substring(1) ?>"
```